# case sensitive/in-sensitive match not working in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

in my `server` directive, the location configuration are as below

```
    location ~ \.(html)$ {
        expires max;
        return 200 "case sensitive match";
    }

    location ~* \.(html)$ {
            expires 10d;
            return 200 "case insensitive match";
    }
```

My expectation is that when I load `localhost/somthing.html` it should print `case sensitive match` and when I load `localhost/something.hTML` it should print `case insensitive match`

However, in both the cases, `case sensitive match` gets printed

The request log in `access.log` is

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2021:17:56:15 +0530] "GET /something.hTML HTTP/1.1" 200 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
```

Attached picture, see the statement printed and also the `expires` which is set to `MAX` proving that `case sensitive match` worked. What could be going wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What operating system is nginx running under?

Comment: Mac, Big Sur, 11.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location ~` matches are still case-insensitive under operating systems with case-insensitive filesystems (such as Mac OS & Windows).

To force a case-insensitive pattern you need to include it in the regex itself with `(?-i)` e.g.

```
location ~ "(?-i)\.(html)$" {
    ...
}
```

See [this (very old) issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/87).